# Re.search dangling metacharacter error

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Okay this line is, in my IDE giving an error of Pattern Expected: Dangling Metacharacter.

```
re.search(*.*.*.*, string)
```

What's wrong and how do I make it work?

Comment: You don't really understand what these stars and dots do, do you? Please read some [explanations and tutorials](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: Hey, I'm used to batch, I'm new to python. I'm assuming that they're wildcards.

Comment: I just googled this and got a bunch of solutions. Perhaps you should do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `.` at the start:

```
re.search('.*.*.*.*', string)
```

A `*` without anything preceding it is a dangling meta-character.

Not that either pattern makes sense; just one `'.*'` would be enough to match all text.

If you are searching for text with *literal* dots, say, in a IP address, then you'd use:

```
re.search('\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', string)
```

e.g. use `\.` to match a literal dot. `\d` matches *one* digit, `+` makes it match 1 or more digits.

I *strongly* urge you to read the [regular expression howto](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) before you continue.

Comment: @user3188034: Your pattern doesn't make any sense; what are you trying to achieve? `.` matches any *one* character except a newline, normally.

Comment: I'm trying to search for things like 1.2.3.4 in a string.

Answer (score 0):

As @Martijn Pieters showed, you want to use this, if you are insistent on regular expressions:

`re.search('\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', string)`

However, this is a fairly straightforward to accomplish using simple string methods as well. I'm assuming by trying to match 4 numbers, delimited by periods, that you want to find what the numbers are.

That regular expression is:

`pattern = re.compile('(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)')`

Using `pattern.search('255.255.255.255').groups()` yields `('255', '255', '255', '255')`.

So, it does what you need it do.

This is a much simpler task using [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

`'255.255.255.255'.split('.')` yields `['255', '255', '255', '255']`.

Why use `str.split` over the regex? Because of performance:

```
import re
from timeit import timeit

to_match = '255.255.255.255'
pattern = re.compile('(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)')

def regex_split():
    pattern.search(to_match).group()

def string_split():
    to_match.split('.')

print timeit(regex_split) # 1.4148 seconds
print timeit(string_split) # 0.7517 seconds
# note: both call the functions 1 million times
```

Thus, `str.split` takes approximately 53% of the time that the regular expression does. A general rule: if the task can be accomplished simply (which of course, is relative) using string methods, use those instead of regular expressions.